# What is Singlet Fermion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, dark-matter

I encountered this term in the paper [Singlet fermionic dark matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2932) by Yeong Gyun Kim *et al* regarding Dark Matter. From my quantum mechanics knowledge singlet would refer to a singlet state which is a quantum state where the total quantum spin would be equal to 0. So is it correct to assume a singlet fermion is a particle with a total spin state to be 0?

Comment: which paper?   Singlet of which group?

Comment: Weak isospin, not spin singlet

Comment: Added paper reference

Comment: Quote from the paper "We propose a renormalizable extension of the SM with a hidden sector which consists of SM gauge singlets (a singlet scalar and a singlet Dirac fermion)." https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462138/gauge-singlet-under-sm

Comment: @alanf super helpful thank you !